# Optimizing query less than date

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query as shown below. I want to use `Less_date` and `date` columns to find a date within them. is there a way to do the same without writing the code for `Less_date` again?

```
select 
    *, 
    select top 1 (date) as Less_date 
    from table1 T2 
    where some complex conditions and 
    where date is < table1.date
    order by date DESC,
    select top 1 (date) as between_date 
    from table1 T3
    where date < t5 and date >t5.Less_date from table1
    and some complex condition
    order by date DESC
from
    table1 
where some complex conditions
```

Right now the only way I found to do this is below but I would like to see if there is any better way to do the same.

```
select *, (select top 1 (date) as between_date from table1 T3
           where date < t5 and date >t5.Less_date
          and some complex condition
          order by date DESC) from
(
select *, 
          (select top 1 (date) as Less_date from table1 T2 
          where some complex conditions and where date is < table1.date
          order by date DESC)
from table1 
where some complex conditions
) t5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're trying to do in your first query in terms of the 2 SELECT subqueries, so this may not be relevant but you could always use the MAX(date_col) function to return the most recent date, rather than the SELECT TOP 1, ORDER BY date_col DESC method you're using right now.

If you're just trying to get the first date common between the 2 columns, you could do something like:

`SELECT MAX(date_col1) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table 1  ON table1.date_col1 = table1.date_col2`

or you could put use SELECT * to get all the common dates between the 2 columns.

Comment: 2 select sub queries are required due to other complex conditions. It is not possible to have a simple select query like what you have shown

Comment: Understood, sorry I couldn't be of more help!